# Save image path to core data, then use the path in a eureka row to show the image

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am trying to save an images path to core data that I can later use to display the image in a row created using Eureka Forms: The below code saves the URL, but I cannot get the file name. Here is what is currently being saved.

file:///Users/myName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/21A03F39-026C-417F-8E51-16C5E4BE2FC8/data/Containers/Data/Application/4A7CAE46-5004-4A2E-93A6-A3581F853576/Documents/

```
@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

     let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectories!)

    print ("STARTS HERE \(url) ENDS")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for saving an image to document directory with an image name. After saving you will get the file URL that will work in future use.

```
let documentsDirectoryURL = try! 
NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, 
  appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
// create a name for your image
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Image1.jpg")

if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL.path!) {
    if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToFile(fileURL.path!, atomically: true) {
        print("file saved")
    } else {
        print("error saving file")
    }
} else {
    print("file already exists")
}
print ("STARTS HERE \(fileURL) ENDS")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using swift 4 and there were a bunch of things that I had to update. There is one update that I cannot figure out. I am getting error: Value of type 'URL' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'

Comment: you can use this for swift 4 

"let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL..appendingPathComponent("Image1.jpg")"